# Wicket exception on page redirect

Tags: java, wicket

I have a wicket page, and on the form submit I do a redirect to another page. I have this:

```
@Override
protected void onSubmit()
{
    //Do something
    response.sendRedirect(previousPageUrl);
}
```

The page was redirected correctly, but I got this exception:

```
[org.apache.wicket.protocol.http.WebResponse] [Unable to redirect to:..., HTTP Response has already been committed.]
[org.apache.wicket.protocol.http.WicketFilter] [closing the buffer error]
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Committed
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Response.resetBuffer(Response.java:1059) ~[na:na]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Response.sendRedirect(Response.java:449) ~[na:na]
    at org.apache.wicket.protocol.http.WebResponse.sendRedirect(WebResponse.java:299) ~[wicket-1.4.17.jar:1.4.17]
    at org.apache.wicket.protocol.http.WebResponse.redirect(WebResponse.java:250) ~[wicket-1.4.17.jar:1.4.17]
    at org.apache.wicket.protocol.http.BufferedWebResponse.close(BufferedWebResponse.java:67) ~[wicket-1.4.17.jar:1.4.17]
```

I already tried to add this line before my `sendRedirect()` call, but it didn't help:

```
getRequestCycleSettings().setRenderStrategy(IRequestCycleSettings.ONE_PASS_RENDER);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to interrupt Wicket's request processing:

```
 throw new RedirectToUrlException(previousPageUrl);
```

Comment: It works. Thanks a lot! Have been spending hours trying figure it out.

Answer (score 1):

My first initial impression on your code is that in your `// do something` you might have written something to the `response` object. You can try to do either commment those codes first to isolate the problem or paste the whole `// do something` here so that we can you help you better.